# CakeDC Search does not search with emptyValue

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I'm not sure if I understand the emptyValue correctly. I want to have ability to filter Users by it's language that is set, but also some users haven't set the language yet, so they have NULL. Here is the code:

```
// Model    
    public $filterArgs = array(
        'locale' => array('type' => 'value', 'field' => 'Profile.locale', 'allowEmpty' => true),
    );

// Controller
    public $presetVars = array(
    'locale' => array('type' => 'value', 'allowEmpty' => true, 'emptyValue' => '0')
    );
```

In DB the field Profile.locale can be NULL and it's default value is NULL. Now the view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->select('locale', am(array('0' => __('Not set')), Configure::read('User.locales'))); ?>
```

That gives me proper HTML:

```
<select name="data[User][locale]" class="input-small" id="UserLocale">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">Not set</option>
<option value="eng">English</option>
<option value="deu">Deutsch</option>
<option value="pol">Polski</option>
</select>
```

But when I try to search and select 'Not set' the locale parametr does not show up in URL. Also when I type by hand `?locale=0` in URL I get in query `WHERE 'Profile'.'locale' = '0'` not `WHERE 'Profile'.'locale' IS NULL`.

I'm using CakeDC Search current developer branch and CakePHP 2.4.6.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the develop branch? This was fixed here https://github.com/CakeDC/search/commit/bb33c6e330cb6fb10de3b23ac583a8d0da86410a so use this commit id or a newer one.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it through composer and see that already have this commit.